# Unable to access method in the delegate

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory-management, delegates, subview

Here's how I set up my app.  I have a root view that loads a subview over the top of it during the viewDidLoad method.  In the subview I have a button that, when clicked, hides itself and reveals the root view.  Everything is working great, but I hate having a view that is loaded but is not in use.  I tried to put a method in the delegate that does this:

```
[theLaunch release];
```

...where `theLaunch` is my Subview.

This method, located in my delegate, is called `hidetheLaunch`.

Then I was trying to call this method from within the subview:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate hidetheLaunch];
```

But it says `-hidetheLaunch not found in protocol`.

Am I doing this all wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to first **cast the `UIApplicationDelegate`** to your specific delegate's type:

```
[((MyAppDelegate *) [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate) hidetheLaunch];
```

Comment: WHen I substitute my delegate name into the code you provided, it says that it is not declared.  Do I need to `#import` the delegate?

Comment: Well, whenever I import the Delegate it causes errors all over my application.  I just decided to skip the whole thing altogether. :)

Comment: @willingfamily That doesn't make sense. Please show us the errors that you're having.

Comment: After importing the Delegate, I get an error in my `RootViewController.m`, `SlideToLaunchAppDelegate.m`, and `firstLaunch.m`.  The error I get is: `Expected specifier-qualifier-list before `firstLaunch`.